# Evaluating $\sqrt[3]\frac{x+y+z}{3}$ for $x=1111×10^{11}$, $y=77777×10^{5}$, $z = 111111$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x=1111\times10^{11}$, $y=77777\times10^{5}$, $z = 111111$ then find the value of $$\sqrt[3]\frac{x+y+z}{3}$$

I obtained these values but how to solve further 
$$x=11×101×10^{11}\\
y=7×41×271×10^{5}\\
z=3×7×11×13×37$$

Comment: Small formatting tip: You can use \cdot for multiplication instead of $X$.

Comment: See if you can find some factors of $x+z$ and compare them to the factors of $y$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers involved can be represented in terms of powers of $10$:
$$\begin{align}1111 &= \frac{10^4-1}{9}\\
77777 &= \frac{10^5-1}{9}\times 7\\
111111 &= \frac{10^6-1}{9}\end{align}$$

Let $a=10^5$.  Then

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{x+y+z}{3} &= \frac{(a^3 -10a^2)+(7a^2-7a)+(10a-1)}{27}\\
&=\frac{a^3 - 3a^2 + 3a - 1}{27}\\
&=\frac{(a-1)^3}{3^3}\\
\end{aligned}$$